# LinearLayout EditText and getChildAt

Tags: android-layout

I got an error when I try to access my last edit text of a linear layout with get child At ?

It works well with the other edit text. I have several linear layouts and for all of them, it's the same : I can't get the last edit text...

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a (re)beginner, and after a few more research I've found my error.
I tried to put an integer value to an `EditText` with `setText()` !
This line with `String.valueOf()` works fine :

```
((EditText) lTNT5.getChildAt(3)).setText(String.valueOf(mConf.TimeSIG));
```

Sorry